# Which class in JMeter reads classes from plugins in lib/ext folder?

Tags: java, plugins, jmeter

Can anybody answer, which *.class is responsible for reading Jmeter plugins list from ./lib/ext? Or where in Jmeter sources elements tree is built?

My problem is that I've built my own JMeter Listener from sources(maven project), but it is not displayed in "Listeners"

I'm able to debug code on runtime, but I do not know which class exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class that finds others is:
- http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jorphan/reflect/ClassFinder.html

It has many methods used in different contexts to find implementations of certains interface

Regarding the tree question I am not sure to inderstand but if it's about the tree model it's:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/gui/tree/JMeterTreeModel.html

Regards

Philippe M.

http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/-Solutions-